# C++ How can I call a template function with a template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a quick question for my program: How can I call this template function with `Set`, rather than `int`?
I have a class here called Set

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> 
class Set
{
public:
    class Iterator;
    void add(T v);
    void remove(T v);
    Iterator begin();
    Iterator end();

private:
    vector<T> data;
};
```

Here's my cpp:
Unfortunately, main cannot be a template function so I had to make another function `addstuff`, which main calls

```
template <class T>
Set<T> addstuff()
{
    Set<T> a;
    a.add(1);
    a.add(2);
    a.add(3);
    a.add("a string");

    return a;
}

void main()
{
    addstuff<Set>(); //<< Error here. If I use addstuff<int>(), it would run but   
                     //I can't add string to it. I am required to be able to add 
                     //different data types to this vector
}
```

Comment: "...required to be able to add difference data types..." - try `boost::any` or limit it to a polymorphic type with the required base class.

Comment: I can't use third party libraries...this is school assignment, unfortunately.

Comment: `boost::any` is not too difficult to implement yourself. Else look into a union then for the types you need to support.

Comment: @Angew Really? Well damn here I am for the past hour scratching my head. I thought you could call `addstuff()` with Set, not just int or string data types

Comment: @imdumb Sorry, I misread the declaration of `addstuff()` (not fully awake yet). The main part of my comment stands, though - `Set` is not a class, it's a template. The way you've written `Set`, each instantiation can only store objects of one type. If you need a container capable of storing objects of different types at the same time, you need polymorphism or type erasure (as Niall suggests).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your writing `addstuff<Set>()` would be an attempt to resolve to `Set<Set> addstuff()` which is meaningless.

`addstuff<std::string>()` *would* allow you to add `std::string`s to your set, but then `a.add(1)` would fail since the literal cannot be implicitly converted to a string type.

`addstuff<int>()` *does* work but that's a merry coincidence. `add(1)` has the correct type in that instance to be added to `Set<int>`.

You *could* build a class `Foo` that has non-explicit constructors to a string and an integer and make that your template type: `addstuff<Foo>()`. But I'm not convinced that's what your professor wants you to do and there are better ways of solving this (type erasure for one, but this is getting quite involved).

Comment: Yeah, I do not think this is possible to throw in string and int at the same time in this vector.